# Powershell system.web.HttpUtility/system.UriBuilder Set encoding

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script, that sends a REST request. for this situation, POST request should be set.
The problem is, even if we are filling it with UTF8 characters like "ščřž", on the other side, it is encoded (%CA%DE and so on), even in POST method, which should not encode it.

I have found, that `parseQueryString`should also take 2nd parameter - encoding, but providing second parameter, it throws an error that cannot find overload for function with 2 parameters.

Simply said - is there any way, how to alter this piece of code to force any other encoding?

(decode on the other side, which is not in my hands, is not an option at the moment)

```
  $pars = [system.web.HttpUtility]::parseQueryString([String]::Empty)
    $param_map = $param_maps[$method][$module]
    $param_map.keys | %{


       if ($psBoundParameters.containsKey($_)) {
            $pars[$param_map[$_]] = $psBoundParameters[$_]
          }
        }
        $request = [system.UriBuilder]"http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:8081/RestService/$http_resource"
        $request.query = $pars.toString()
        $uri = $request.uri

function contact-server {
  try {
    $response = invoke-webrequest -uri $uri -credential $credential -body @{x = 'x'} -method $http_method -useBasicParsing
   ###
  }
  catch{
  ###
  }
```

}

thanks in advance

Comment: What does the URI have to do with encoding of the request body? In your example the only parameter you pass in the body is `x` with the payload `x`

Comment: Yes, that is true. The payload contains various of data. The issue is, that POST method should not encode it. For example, calling this REST message with name=Aleš will output name=Ale%C5%A1 on the other side, even if POST method should not do it (GET method does it, that's ok). Simply, I need to send the characters via POST method as is, without encoding. that's why I am looking for some possibilities to use other encodings and hope, it will get through right.

Comment: And this article also says, the ParseQueryString should accept encoding parameter, but it does not in Powershell. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's an encoding option, but it has to be type [System.Text.Encoding].  It's not like an enum that can be converted from a string.  `[system.text.encoding]::utf8` would work.

```
PS C:\> Using assembly System.Web
PS C:\> Using namespace System.Web
PS C:\> [HttpUtility]::parseQueryString

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection ParseQueryString(string query)
static System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection ParseQueryString(string query,
System.Text.Encoding encoding)

PS C:\> [HttpUtility]::parseQueryString('hi', [system.text.encoding]::utf8)
```